# PCA to decorrelate variables

Tags: correlation, pca

I have 2 variables that I want to decorrelate. I was told I can use PCA to do so. I did PCA on the data and got all the parameters. Now how do I get the new set of transformed data that no longer correlates with the second variable? I want to use this set for further analysis.
thanks,

Comment: PCA gives you two new variables that have zero correlation with each other (see @whuber's answer). It seems that what you really wanted is to transform one variable so that it has zero correlation with another, untrasformed, one. You don't need PCA for that. Simply regress variable 1 onto variable 2 and take the residuals as your new variable 1. These residuals are guaranteed to have zero correlation with variable 2.

Answer (score 9):

With just two variables $X$ and $Y$, there are two sample variances $s^2$ and $t^2$, respectively, and the sample correlation coefficient, $r$.  If you standardize the variables in the usual way to have unit variances, so that $\xi = X/s$ and $\eta = Y/t$, then the two principal components are

$$PC_1 = \xi+\eta = X/s + Y/t, \quad PC_2 = \xi-\eta = X/s - Y/t.$$

As a check, note that Covar($PC_1, PC_2$) = Var($X/s$) - Var($Y/t$) = $1-1=0$, proving the components are orthogonal (uncorrelated).

**Visually:** when you plot a scatterplot of $X$ and $Y$ in which the coordinate axes are expressed in standard units and have an aspect ratio of 1:1, then the axes of the point cloud fall along diagonal lines parallel to $X=Y$ and $X=-Y$.

[image: Scatterplot]

In this example the variances are $s^2 = 0.98$, $t^2 = 7.90$ and the correlation is $r=-0.67$.  Because $X$ and $Y$ are plotted on standardized scales with unit aspect ratio, the major axis of the cloud is diagonal (downward, due to negative correlation).  This is the first principal component, $X/s-Y/t$.  The minor axis of the cloud is also diagonal (upward) and forms the second principal component, $X/s+Y/t$.

Comment: thanks. I know the 2 components are not correlated, but I want one transformed variable to be uncorrelated with the second untrasformed variable.

Comment: @Abeer And that's exactly what I have shown for $X/s-Y/t$ and $X/s+Y/t$.

Comment: This is a good answer, but unfortunately to the misunderstood question. As clarified by the OP in the comment above, what they really wanted was to transform one variable so that it had zero correlation with another, *untrasformed*, one. To clarify for future readers: PCA is not needed for that. Simply regress variable 1 onto variable 2 and take the residuals as the new variable 1. These residuals are guaranteed to have zero correlation with variable 2. Done. @whuber: This is a popular thread (1k views); perhaps you could add this to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It varies with your software, but you should have something like a component score matrix. Multiply that with your original variables to get the new set of transformed data.

Comment: with R you do get a score matrix. in my case with 2 columns/components. I tried that and I get some weird scatter plot. I plot variable1 vs variable2*score.component1

Answer (score 1):

You have loading for each component (P1, P2,....Pi).

$$P_1=l_1x_1+l_2x_2+...+l_jx_j$$
$$P_2=l_1x_1+l_2x_2+...+l_jx_j$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$P_i=l_1x_1+l_2x_2+...+l_jx_j$$

where $x$ is orginal data and $P_i$ is rotated component. The important is loadings ($l_1,l_2,...,l_j$). If you mulitple them with orginal data then you will get rotated Principle components.
For more information check this [URL](http://ordination.okstate.edu/PCA.htm).